# Making a really long/tall mohawk stand

Tags: hair

My [mohawk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohawk_hairstyle) has grown unmanageably tall and the usual styling products aren't strong enough to stand it up anymore...

Mustache wax works for shorter 1-4 inch mohawks.
The usual hairsprays and mouses usually fail at about the 6-10 inch range.

My mohawk is now closer to 18 inches, well over the failure point of conventional products.

So, what else can I use?

Answer (score 3):

I've found that clear [Elmer's School Glue Gel](http://elmers.com/product/detail/E364) works well.

[image]

It is non-toxic and it is water-soluble so it washes away easily enough, just have to let water run over it for a couple minutes before the glue softens enough to shampoo.

Probably the best part is that you can stand a mohawk up for more than one day with it, provided that you're comfortable sleeping on your side.

Comment: Note that there was some fuss in the UK a few years ago when Rolls-Royce sacked a young employee who had been using a mix of Evo-Stick and Super Glue to hold his spiky style in place on the grounds that there was a risk of him damaging the paintwork and of his hair causing injury to co-workers.  IIRC the industrial tribunal found for Rolls-Royce.

Comment: @SteveBarnes That's great. I used to joke about putting straight pins in the tips of mine to discourage people from wanting to touch it =)